# Why are long haul touring bikes sold with 9-speed drivetrains?

Tags: drivetrain, touring-bikes

Following up on [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/82571/touring-bike-with-good-support-network-in-india), I had a look on the specifications of 'long haul touring bikes', such as the [Trek 520](https://www.trekbikes.com/gb/en_GB/bikes/bikepacking-and-touring-bikes/520/f/F251/), [Salsa Marrakesh](https://www.salsacycles.com/bikes/2021_marrakesh_alivio), and [Surly Disc Trucker](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/disc_trucker). One thing that surprised me was that they are all equipped with Shimano Sora/Alivio — "upper-entry level parts, 9 speed only", while these are bikes in the 1.5 k€-2 k€ range. For comparison: similarly priced road bikes typically have mid-range products — Shimano 105/GRX600 (11-speed), and flat handle bar bikes would have upper-range transmissions — Shimano XT (12-speed).

These transmissions are considered to be "upper entry level" ranges. Why not use higher product ranges? I understood that mid-range products are manufactured with better materials and tighter tolerances, so that should have a positive impact on reliability for long trips?

What would be the reason to use this kind of transmission rather than for example a 10-speed based system (Tiagra or Deore(XT) trekking for example)? Or older products from upper ranges with 9 speed (to provide more "refined" component, and that could be easily replaced if it they need a replacement during a tour)?

Is it linked to durability, availability of spare parts across the world or simply compatibility — to use brifters and MTB products? Or is it simply cost saving because all the money went into manufacturing of high quality frames? What is the experience of those who have experience with this kind of usage?

Comment: Good question. Maybe they wanted triple chainrings for wider gear range. The current Shimano 105 and upwards groupsets only have single or dual chainrings. But the Shimano Tiagra would totally be an option and yet they didn’t use it. Maybe their customers just don’t want/need smaller gear steps and lower weight.

Comment: Related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/82571/touring-bike-with-good-support-network-in-india

Comment: Is there a significant overlap of 9 speed setups with bikes that have bar-end shifters ?  10 speed is where MTB and road groupsets start to diverge in compatibility.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Tourers benefit from triples, and if you're going to run a triple, 3x10 doesn't offer much on top of 3x9.

There are two technical reasons to prefer triples.  The first is *gear range*:

- A typical 1x11 setup gives 11-42T at the back, for a difference of 3.8:1
- A 2x10 or 2x11 drivetrain might come with 46/30x11-30, for a difference of 4.2:1. That's GRX, meant for gravel bikes - road setups are geared a little higher but have a similar range, though I now have exactly that range in 105 on the road wheels for my gravel/endurance bike, Some 2x10 mountain setups go wider, as do 2x11 gravel (I have an 11-34 cassette on my gravel wheel).
- The stock 3x9 Sora on my tourer was 50/39/30x11-32, for a range of 4.8:1 (and you could put 11-34 on the back easily, stretching this still further)

You may well be slogging up hill for long periods, laden, so you need low gears.  The top end on my tourer sees less use but there are certainly sustained descents where it's useful.

The second, that has been a great help to me, is *fault-tolerance*.  There are 2 factors here:

- A 9-speed derailleur works tolerably well even if not set up perfectly and it's easy to index.  Even with a slightly bent hanger or axle you can get a good range of gears without ghost shifting (when my axle was bent, I could get both ends OK, but had some ghost shifting in the middle of the cassette.  If you trash your derailleur and can only get something even more basic, you'll still be able to ride even if it's not perfect.
- Parts break unexpectedly.  Normally this is cables.  My RD cable usually lasts around 5000km, but has been under 4000km.  I get about 50km of warning, when I think "that's funny, I adjusted it not long ago".  Bike shops can be much further than that apart, and carrying a spare inner doesn't always solve it as the outer can be damaged.  But with a triple, you can lock off the RD and get quite a long way on a wide-ratio 3-speed.  I've done 200km that way. Since then I've done something similar after messing up changing the cable and jamming it in the shifter - 500km of a recent tour was done on 3 speeds (though I selected a sprocket for the riding conditions each day).

Closely related is durability of all drive-train parts, but that's been addressed in other answers already.

In addition to the technical reasons to like triples, look at the *availability around  brakes*.

High end groupsets normally come with hydraulic braking.  Decent hydraulics can be very nice, but cheap ones are horrid (I've got some on my MTB and I'm seriously considering getting rid of them - performance is poor and they're a pain to service; I may even have a leak).  But even good hydraulics have failure modes that are hard to deal with at the roadside; they're also prone to fade if you have to ride the brakes on long descents.

A lot of tourers come with cable discs.  I've had my issues with these too, but sintered metal pads on cables are as heat-proof as you can get for those long heavy descents.  A spare cable can be carried and there's never any need for bleeding. Short of trashing a caliper or lever most things can be fixed at the roadside, and any old bike shop could do something about a broken lever.

While bar-end shifters help separate the braking from the gears, some of us like brifters on tourers, and anyway, high-end groupsets only come with brifters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation: out of curiosity, what is the proportion of tourers that use "flat bar" derivatives (either with bar-ends or butterfly?) Reading you, it looks like drop bars are actually quite constraining if you want to tour in hilly/mountainous areas (on roads). First because road transmissions are less skewed toward speed rather than torque (even with a comparable range), and second for the separation of braking and transmission. I imagine that some would rather have a MTB/trekking transmission than a drop bar, if they had to choose only one.

Comment: @Renaud I was only thinking of drop bars.  I know people with flat bar tourers, but I reckon butterfly bars are always after-market, and I rarely see them.  Drop bars don't inherently force road transmissions, and I know from experience that Sora and Alivio (9 speed) are compatible - I can borrow the back wheel off my MTB, and while I haven't tried it I'm pretty certain I could swap on an MTB triple crankset (I know I could fit a smaller chainring).  Then of course there are gravel groupsets these days, with MTB-like ratios but built for drop bars.

Comment: But sometimes I wonder if I would have been better off converting my trekking hybrid to drop bars for touring, and getting an endurance road bike instead.  I would have been glad of the weight saving yesterday, for example

Comment: True, it was a bit of a disgression. MTB transmission are still ahead of gravel transmission in term of range, so I was wondering how popular they were among tourers — no those who go to developing countries though. To give an example, the  M8000 3x11 had 40/30/22 front, 11/40 rear, that gives a range of 661% (with highs and lows that more suited to touring I think). The latest 2x12 from Shimano are at 620%, but they may be less good on the fault-tolerance and durability sides). The trekking range (Alivio to XT) has 600% in 3x, for comparison. And GRX tops at 500%.

Comment: @Renaud already by 11 speed you're getting into serious durability concerns, but that range would be nice at times

Comment: @Renaud now I have effectively a sub-compact 2x11 setup, that 3x11 seems very low for touring, even touring with some gravel. I find myself spinning out in 46/11 if I want to carry speed from descents, for example

Comment: that's indeed a MTB groupset, so there's indeed a bias towards low speeds. In 11-speed, I'm quite interested by the combinations offered in the new CUES range, especially the 46/30 front and 11/45 rear (my fun bike has 46/30 front and 11/42 rear).

Comment: Hi ChrisH, I remember we had a discussion about the (lack of) range of GRX 2x somewhere else, I learnt recently a trick that may interest you: the RD-RX812 (1x11 GRX rear derailleur, rated for 11-42 cassettes) actually uses the same cage as the RD-M8000-GS (short cage XT rear derailleur). Apparently, you can change the plates of the cage and take the ones of the RD-M8000-SGS (long cage, which differs from the GS by the capacity, can be bought separately), and then run it with a 48/31 (or 46/30) crankset, which would then give a range of 591% (or 585%).

Comment: @Renaud I wonder if there's an equivalent trick starting from a 105 RD.  I'll have to look into it.  Thanks

Comment: I doubt, the trick doesn't seem to work with the 2x11 version of the GRX 810, that seems to be the "rugged version" of the 105/Ultegra. The 1x11 has a parallelogram designed to accommodate 11/42 cassettes, but doesn't have the capacity to cope with with a double crankset with the standard/short cage. This is addressed by the changing the cage. The 2x11 are designed on the other hands for 11/34 cassettes, some people claim that they can work with larger cassettes (with goat links), but my understanding of derailleurs let me think that starting from the 1x11 is a much better starting point.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kUxmkuJWNg - even works with a 11/46 cassette, but that seems to be too far stretched to me (I'm tempted to try with an 11-42, as it would remain within the specs of the parallelogram and the M8000-SGS, but I may try after having worn the current cassette).

Answer (score 15):

Another detail not mentioned in other answers is spare parts availability. Drivetrain parts at 9-speed and below are much more cross-compatible with each other than current middle to high tier parts, and commonly available because cheap bikes are popular. Together it means that when you need spare parts on a trip, there is a better chance that the nearest repair shop or sports store has something that fits.  The same applies to V-brakes, 1 1/8” headsets, QR hubs, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is a little slippery because while it's not the case now, there was a period of time where the Microshift Shimano mountain 10 bar-ends didn't exist yet and so the spec options became very limited if you wanted to mass produce a 10-speed bar-end shifter bike with a 34 on the back, since none of the road rear derailleurs in the Shimano lineup could do that, and the mountain ones need mountain 10 cable pull. (You could use a mountain 9 RD and it would work perfectly, but it's a frankenbike on paper then and manufacturers don't love that). Some touring bikes made it out into the world in those years taking advantage of the SRAM road 10/mountain 10 cross-compatibility and came with full SRAM groups, which itself was mediocre for touring bikes in terms of wear life of the parts, and was a fairly expensive way of doing it at the time.

The Microshift bar-ends have always been kind of blah compared to the action of the Shimano ones. The detents are indeterminate and can require fiddling that the shifters they copy don't. There have been yet other times when companies had the option of speccing either Microshift bar ends for Shimano mountain 10 once they became available or staying with SL-BS77, the Shimano 9 bar-ends, a Dura-Ace level part that show it by being essentially the best and most durable indexed bar-end or thumbshifter that has ever been made. Those are no longer in production and in my opinion the quality of the Microshift parts is a little better now (incrementally), so again the answer is a little different at this moment compared to the past.

Note that some jump to the logic that if the demand for the bikes is there than the parts will follow. That is true to some extent but it's not automatic in the cycling industry. Loaded touring bikes are a fringe category from a commercial perspective and there's a lot of impetus to borrow parts from other applications.

Above concerns aside there are arguments that loaded touring bikes suffer from each generation of narrower chain. Each increase has required more finicky adjustment and increased the cost and hassle factor of maintaining the bike. With touring bikes it's always hard to accurately estimate how many that are sold live mostly garage-bound lives, used very occasionally for vacation or other special events, and how many are taken advantage of for their station-wagon factor and become heavily ridden commuter/utilitarian bikes. Generally speaking there is a tension between the two groups, where one would very much like to have the latest and greatest with the most dialed and luxurious contact points and where long-term wear life is not much of a concern, and another where the more stripped down and basic the running gear can be the better as long as the functionality is there. You can find examples on various bikes of both groups winning, i.e. for the last couple decades you can find examples of loaded touring bikes that go all-in on the vacation set via-à-vis STI and road triples etc, and the bikes are thusly bad at climbing mountains or going forever. Some have even really copped out and gone to compact double. A lot of the impetus now with keeping the bikes at 9 is using 9-speed chains and shifting as a line the sand where going further isn't worth it on a loaded touring bike, especially for the cost on a bike category where some segment of the market is viewing the purchase even at that price point as a budget-stretching one-bike-to-do-everything and not as a vacation luxury item.

In my view, the "right" number is almost certainly 7, because then you get the advantage of a much stronger rear wheel due to the wider, more even bracing angles and better non-drive-side tension. In the average case scenario, that is more valuable on a loaded touring bike than all the advantages of going to a bigger number. A good counterpoint is we can now see that hanging the 34t cog over the drive side hub flange à la mountain 11 was an option all along that for no good reason just didn't happen back in the day, so the "right" number is actually 8 or 9 but on cassettes that don't exist.

Comment: Isn’t the bad spoke angle problem on rear wheels kind of solved by newer, wider hubs (with disc brakes) and/or asymmetric rims?

Comment: @Michael Those make it closer to symmetrical (make the distances between the flanges and the hub center relatively closer), so yes they give you more NDS tension in both cases, but with assymetric rims you're merely redistributing the bracing angles and with going to disc you're steepening one and the leaving the other as-is, so the net situation is weaker to side-loads, not stronger. There hasn't been a widening of rear hubs as it applies to these kinds of bikes - that only is true of boost bikes.

Comment: RE those dura-ace bar-ends, everyone loved them, but, I have had a 100% failure rate with them (2 pairs, both broke internally, then herniated. (different rider, different bike). The microshift bar ends (4 pair) have never failed us, though we use the thumb version (same mech, different mount). I'm surprised by the longevity of 9 too -- but it's fine by me. I like 9 speed b/c I feel like the derailleur adjustments are a bit easier, and the compatibility between Shimano road/mtn shifter/derailleur is there. Makes frankenbike development so much simpler. It went complex and confusing after 10.

Comment: It's not just bar-end shifters though - 9-speed Sora brifters are certainly used on tourers as well

Comment: @ChrisH Indeed: the Trek 520 comes with Sora brifters for examples

Comment: @ChrisH my premise there was that, for example, there have been periods where if a manufacturer wanted to go the bar-end direction, they got somewhat shoehorned into staying 9-speed.

Comment: @NathanKnutson I'm sure that's true.  I'm not sure how many tourers use bar-end shifters vs. brifters so how significant it is.  I know mine and the Trek 520 use brifters, My friend's LHT and a Salsa I looked at a few years ago had bar-end

Comment: @ChrisH On the list I've given: only the Salsa I've given uses bar-end. And I've seen that one of the versions of the Kona Sutra uses Microshift 10 speed bar-ends with Deore transmission, another version uses a Shimano GRX 400 with Tiagra brifters and TRP hydraulic brakes.

Comment: Personally, and I realize opinions differ, I think what's happened is that product managers have kind of the come to the calculus that since the Microshift ones are a little unlovely anyway, the better business decision is skip the whole conversation and go with STI since it's a chase feature in so many biker buyers' minds.

Answer (score 0):

A ridiculous number of speeds isn't the most advanced technology. About the only case where you benefit from more than 7 or 8 speeds in the rear is 1x drivetrains, which are most beneficial in mountain bikes because road bikes necessitate a 50+ teeth chainring to go at any reasonable speed with good efficiency, and multiple really big rear sprockets (biggest of them 50+ teeth) would increase the weight more than a second smaller chainring. Also on road riding you have plenty of time to switch between chainrings, but for MTB use you might not have.

In fact, I would argue that technology is going backwards in bicycles in contrast to every single other device like motor vehicles, computers, cameras, electronics, etc.

Long-haul touring bikes are very similar to other road bikes: you want the ability to ride at great speeds, plus the ability to climb steep hills. About the only difference is that riding those steep hills standing might not be so easy because riding standing necessitates rocking the bike, and rocking the bike takes lots of energy if the bike is loaded with cargo. So in contrast to 2x systems of road bikes, touring bikes very often have a 3x system to allow riding steep hills sitting, although with a very wide range cassette a 2x compact 34/50 system could be adequate.

Why would you need 10+ speeds on a touring bike? There's limited space on the rear cassette. Every new added sprocket makes the sprockets thinner and also makes the chain thinner. Thus you can expect them to last less with the same level of technology (although steel quality has improved so usually the higher sprocket count components are sold with better steel, largely negating the difference). Also more speeds usually mean more expensive components.

If for example you want 16% difference between sprockets, and 11-tooth small sprocket, this would put the big sprocket at 31 teeth on 8-speed systems and 36 teeth on 9-speed systems.

Another good question might be why other bicycle types find lots of sprockets so alluring? With mountain bikes it's due to the prevalence of 1x drivetrains that have clear benefits if you absolutely need the ability to switch gears quickly without anticipation in all conditions. With road bikes I'm sure it's due to road riders wanting to imitate their favorite road racing idol who uses N sprockets in the rear not because of needing N sprockets but because road racing is marketing the latest and "greatest" bicycle components. For regular road riding without imitating bike racing, 7-9 speed cassettes are the optimal choice. MTBs might want to use 10 sprockets or more due to using 1x drivetrains.

Comment: I frequently do haooen to long for more sprockets on my 8 speed gravel bike. Not too much off-road, but on the road one simply cannot go at the cadence one would like to go. Frequently, I shift because the cadence already became unpleasant only to find that after the shift it is even worse and I have to shift back. I cannot agree that more gears are only to copy TV stars.

Comment: In the old times road cyclists just were used to grinding and were fine with 12-25 cassettes and 8 or 9 speed is fine for that. But ordinary people want much wider gear ranges for the steep hills.

Comment: Agree with Vladimir. The 10 speed 11–34 cassette on my cyclocross/touring bike has some uncomfortably big steps (13%, 15%, 18%). A 9 speed cassette would have even more of the big steps (though still none over 18%). On paper the differences don’t look that big but with the 11 speed 11–32 on my road bike I definitely have an easier time finding the “right” gear and cadence.

Comment: MTB 1X is largely driven by the benefit of removing the front derailleur and freeing up space around  highly stressed and crowded BB and suspension pivot area. This space is used by frame designers for a combination of suspension geometry improvements, weight savings and strength increase.

Comment: Well, long haul touring is one of the rare applications where a number of speeds and a wide range makes sense: long hauls trips are typically done with a big variety of landscapes, on a loaded bike and for long durations. Having more intermediate steps would totally make sense to optimize your cadence and minimize the strain. The same way semi-trucks have more speeds than cars.

Comment: @Renaud Semi truck gearboxes are because big diesel engines have very limited RPM range compared to a small one or a gas engine. Touring cyclists have the same RPM range as any other cyclist, so it’s not a perfect comparison. Point taken though.

Comment: @MaplePanda I don't believe I'm unusual in finding my comfortable cadence reduces when tired - and on long tours your legs will be tired.  I lose from both ends but especially the top

Comment: @ChrisH I did not think of that! You’d know best :)

Comment: @MaplePanda when I posted that I was still feeling yesterday's rather tough 200km so it was lucky timing and even my *walking* cadence was affected.  A lazy day then half an hour of unicycle practice loosened up the legs nicely

Comment: @VladimirF the ability to grind a too-high gear for long periods would rather limit who can ride hills.  Kudos to those that can keep that up, but it's great there are options for those of us that can't (and there always have been within the limits of the tech. - there were 15-speed tourers 50 years ago)

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, tourers were available, but road racers, that the industry was supposedly (according to the answer) copycating, had (2x) 53-39x12-25 or similar ranges. Triples in the front were necessary for higher ranges with a 5-speed freewheel.